# Trying to hide menu items off screen with a transition but they collapse down instead?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, nav

My menu items are dropping down when I want to hide them off screen with CSS transitions.

I have attempted using `display: none` on the list items and leaving the menu text, and then on my hover trying to unset to call it back however the items wouldn't return.

CSS

```
nav {
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #800020;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
    margin-left: 90%;
}

nav:hover {
    margin-left: 275px;
}

nav > ul li {
    color: beige;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu {
    color: black;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu"><b>MENU</b></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My goal is to just have the menu text showing and when it's hovered on have it extend out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space:nowrap` on the `ul` to stop the `li` elements from wrapping.

```css
nav {
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #800020;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
    margin-left: 90%;
}

nav:hover {
    margin-left: 275px;
}
nav > ul {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
nav > ul li {
    color: beige;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu {
    color: black;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu"><b>MENU</b></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! I added that and then ```overflow: hidden``` into the nav selector as well, then increased ```#menu```'s padding by 5 to hide the rest of the text and that was it.